# Get the direction arrow toward the SCNNode once that node is not visible in ARCamera

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit, scnnode

If ARCamera moving left, right, up or down and if that node becomes invisible in ARCamera. I want to indicate the arrow that you need to move camera up/down/right/left.

Comment: Hello, Did you found a way to detect the direction of the node i.e. left or right.? It would be helpful if you can provide some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if let pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView{
        let isMaybeVisible = sceneView.isNode((displayNode.presentation), insideFrustumOf: pointOfView)
        if isMaybeVisible{
            if arrowVisible{
                 arrow.removeFromParentNode()
            }
        }else{
            if !arrowVisible{
                 sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(arrow)
            }
        }
    }
```

[`isNode(_:insideFrustumOf:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522647-isnode) here checks if node is visible in ARCamera.

 Use it inside `renderer(_:updateAtTime:)`

Edit: 
Arrow here is a node (3d arrow). Remember the point of arrow need to face -z axis

```
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/arrow.dae")
    let arrow = scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "arrow", recursively: false)
    arrow.constraints = [SCNLookAtConstraint.init(target: node)]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer and it works for 1st step. What about the direction toward that node which not visible in ARCamera?

Comment: arrow in above code needs `arrow.constraints = [SCNLookAtConstraint.init(target: displayNode)]` [SCNLookAtConstraint](http://example.com)

Comment: Thanks @Alok Subedi

Comment: sorry for late ;)
I tried above-suggested way but not work. Maybe due to I'm doing wrong? :)

Can you please post the sample code for arrow/direction toward node is placed?

Comment: Hello @AlokSubedi, Can you please provide a sample code of hot to detect direction of the Node i.e. left or right. It will be helpful.